# Why IS NOT NULL condition works much slower than IFNULL(col, '') <> ''

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, join, mariadb

I have a sql query comprising of several table joins, and ending with a WHERE clause checking on the NULL condition. The Query is like below:-

**Query 1**

```
Select * from TableA ta INNER JOIN TableB tb ON ta.id = tb.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableC tc ON ta.id = tc.txn_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableD td ON tc.sr_no = td.sr_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableE te ON te.name = td.name
WHERE tc.status IS NOT NULL
```

Above query works very slow, but slightly reframing the query using IFNULL condition resolves the issue. Above query slightly modified below:-

**Query 2**

```
Select * from TableA ta INNER JOIN TableB tb ON ta.id = tb.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableC tc ON ta.id = tc.txn_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableD td ON tc.sr_no = td.sr_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableE te ON te.name = td.name
WHERE IFNULL(tc.status,'') <>''
```

My questions are:-

1) Why does Query 1 takes too much time, but Query 2 gives result very quickly?

2) Query 1 is getting created by hibernate's Restriction criteria, by using Restrictions.isNotNull("aliasName.colName"). So is there a way to apply the same condition of NOT null by hibernate restrictions, but without isNull method? (so that Query 2 could be generated ultimately)

3) In the same query, if I remove the NOT condition, it works fine. So Why IS NULL condition works perfectly fine, but IS NOT NULL takes too much time to give result, i.e. why do IS NULL and IS NOT NULL behaves so differently?

P.S. I am using indexes on all of the columns being used in JOIN/condition checking. And I am using mariaDB, which is pretty similar to mySQL.

**Any help is highly appreciated!**

Comment: `IFNULL()` can be preventing the use of an index.  On occasion, indexes don't help, so that might have something to do with the difference in performance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  You do seem to have a point. But when I run the EXPLAIN on the query, I see that in one of the joins, for query 1, index doesn't get used. But for Query 2, indexes get used for all the joins. So looking at the EXPLAIN, it seems the reverse, all indexes are used if I use IFNULL, and it is the IS NOT NULL, which is somehow blocking the use of index.

Comment: . . Indexes can be like that.  When you have multiple indexes, you have multiple different plans.  Which one gets chosen is based on heuristics or table statistics.

Comment: @shanti - Please share the `EXPLAINs`.

Comment: @RickJames: Will sharing just one row of the EXPLAIN be sufficient? I can see only one row corresponding to one specific join giving different result when EXPLAIN is run for the two queries. Unfortunately, I can't share the exact query and the full explain, but I can share the specific row of EXPLAIN output where difference is visible between the two scenario.

Comment: @shanti - Can you concoct a test case that does not include any proprietary info?  You can probably leave out tD and tE.

Comment: @RickJames: sure I will try to do that. But it may take some time. There are 10 JOINS in the actual query and the table may be complex ones. To reproduce same scenario with test tables may need some effort, but I will try to do that surly.